# Eclipse with API 11 can't see BlueStacks

Tags: android, eclipse, bluestacks

I am creating a project which minimum API lvl is 11, and max - API lvl 19. The thing is that I'm using BlueStacks as emulator, and when I'm trying to run my android project, eclipse can't see emulator. Where is the problem and how can I fix it? 
P.S.
My BlueStacks is working fine, and Eclipse can see the emulator when projects min API lvl is 8.

Answer (score 0):

run bluestack first, the open eclipse..